# How to use the admin/ route properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to make an app that has a public area and an admin dashboard.

For the public area, Im using only a controller named Public, and for it, a lot of views. Each view is an area of my front-end, and the are and under the folder **views/public**. They are pages like contact, about us, etc.. But at the end, I dont wanna have the **public** word on my urls. I just want to vist something like: http://localhost:3000/contact and go to the right place. The same goes to the form inside this contact view.

And I have another problem with the admin. First I have created the **Admin** controller, with its views: **index, login** and **logout**. After that, I did an **Events** controller, with the views: **index, new, edit, show, delete, destroy and update**.

So, I dont know if Im thinking this right, but after searching about this subject, I did a scope route like this for the events controller:

```
scope module: 'admin', path: 'admin' do
    resources :events do    
        member do
            get :delete
          end
      end
  end
```

I had to put the events views under the folder **views/admin** and then change the controller classes names, puting **Admin::** before their names. Also, the controllers **Admin** and **Events** are now under the folder **controllers/admin**.

The **Events** controller and its views seem working right. Even the CRUD urls. But I dont know how to put the **Admin** controller routes under the **admin scope**.
My intention is to make an url like this work: **http://localhost:3000/admin/**
and it should take me to: **admin/admin#index**

I have tried to put **Admin** routes under admin scope too, but it didnt work. It was like this:

```
scope module: 'admin', path: 'admin' do
    get 'admin/index'
    get 'admin/login'
    get 'admin/logout'
    resources :events do    
        member do
            get :delete
          end
      end
  end
```

I have tried this too:

```
scope module: 'admin', path: 'admin' do
    get 'index'
    get 'login'
    get 'logout'
    resources :events do    
        member do
            get :delete
          end
      end
  end
```

Didnt work either. Am I thinking right about this route thing? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: For non-namespaced, non `admin/admin`, just `admin/` which goes to `controllers/admin_controller.rb`, use `controller :admin do;
    get 'admin/', action: :index;
  end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell which controller should handle `index`, `login` and `logout`...

If you want a namespaced AdminController like Admin::AdminController, you can do that

```
namespace :admin do
  controller :admin do
    get '/', action: :index
    get :login
    get :logout
  end
  resources :events
end
```

It will generate these routes

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
           admin GET    /admin(.:format)                 admin/admin#index
     admin_login GET    /admin/login(.:format)           admin/admin#login
    admin_logout GET    /admin/logout(.:format)          admin/admin#logout
    admin_events GET    /admin/events(.:format)          admin/events#index
                 POST   /admin/events(.:format)          admin/events#create
 new_admin_event GET    /admin/events/new(.:format)      admin/events#new
edit_admin_event GET    /admin/events/:id/edit(.:format) admin/events#edit
     admin_event GET    /admin/events/:id(.:format)      admin/events#show
                 PATCH  /admin/events/:id(.:format)      admin/events#update
                 PUT    /admin/events/:id(.:format)      admin/events#update
                 DELETE /admin/events/:id(.:format)      admin/events#destroy
```

Comment: it worked. But for the admin area, i had to move all my views of my **Admin** controller to the folder **views/admin/admin**. The layout files included. 
So, now, on my **Events** controller, I have to call the layout like this: **layout "admin/admin"**. Is it ok to keep it like that?

Comment: Even with a namespace, the default place where rails search for a layout file when you change it is on `views/layout`... for layouts on that place, you could just call it as `admin` (for `views/layout/admin.html.erb`)

If you placed your layout file somewhere else, it's only a matter of set the correct place... on your place, I would just create an `admin.html.erb`, place it on `views/layout` and on controllers who render it add `layout :admin`

Comment: ok @cefigueiredo, I moved it back to views/layout and its working, but not on my controller **Admin**. I had to put there the line **layout "admin"** to make it work. 
But, why? The controller doesnt search automatically for a layout that has his name?

Comment: No... A default is already set on `ApplicationController::Base` inherited by `ApplicationController`, that is `application` pointing to `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

You just need setup the layout, if you don't want use the default. 
The only template that react with the name of controller is for the actions and partials... index, show, edit... but they act like partials that are rendered inside the layout...

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help @cefigueiredo!

Answer (score 0):

Specify your public routes

```
get "/contact",       to: "public#contact",       as: :contact
```

Separate your admin routes:

```
namespace :admin do 
    get  :login,    to: "admin#login"
    post :logout,   to: "admin#logout"
    root "admin#root"
end
```